# PermGen Space error during the fillReport function

Tags: java, jasper-reports, out-of-memory

I am getting the following PermGen space error in executing the

```
    JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportFile.getPath(), parameters, conn);
```

in the following code block:

```
    compileFileName = parameters.get("reportName").toString();
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

    ServletContext context = (ServletContext) externalContext.getContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

    ReportConfigUtil.compileReport(context, getCompileDir(), getCompileFileName());

    File reportFile = new File(ReportConfigUtil.getJasperFilePath(context, getCompileDir(), getCompileFileName()+".jasper"));


    Class.forName(ReportsConstants.DRIVER);
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ReportsConstants.DB_ACCESS_URL, ReportsConstants.DB_ACCESS_USER_NAME, ReportsConstants.DB_ACCESS_PASSWORD);

    parameters.put("BaseDir", reportFile.getParentFile());

    JasperPrint jasperPrint =  JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportFile.getPath(), parameters, conn);
```

The error I am receiving is the following:

```
    Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
... 19 more
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
```

My development environment is the following: JSF, PrimeFaces, Hibernate, JasperReports ,Sybase.

What do you friends suggest me to do for resolving the problem?

Comment: As I have read this is some kind of web container issue. You need to restart container after few application deployment.

Comment: Dear Damian, please forgive my illiterature about web container issue. How can I restart it? I am using Tomcat by the way.

Comment: Ok you mean server  as for web container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the perm gen space can make this problem go away. Adding the following parameter will increase it to 128m

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

I'm not sure that you can do much in your code to reduce the amount of perm gen space that is being consumed, so I think any solution will have to do with altering the JVM runtime parameters.

You could also consider trying

```
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
```

as well.

Comment: Dear Dave, I don't know how to do that setting and found nothing on net. Could you please assist me in that setting? Thanks

Comment: Dear DaveHowes, on the netbeans I found the configurations for setting the JVM and tried the two solutions. However, they didn't work. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You need to add these parameters to the JVM that Tomcat runs in, not the JVM that Netbeans runs in ( I don;t know much about Netbeans I'm afraid )